# How Lord Krishna explains on "Knowledge is power"?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

We all know from Bhagavat gita's

> Chapter Seven: 'Knowledge of the Absolute'

Lord Krishna said a lot about knowledge but is there any other proof of him accepting what He said in this chapter?

Any past references or story will work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through this link of Chepter number 7 of gita with more explanation may be its use ful to you http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/chapter-view

Comment: Thanks @BhavinPatel. I already checked it out. It only focuses on Bhagvat Gita. I'm talking about out of that context. If that possible. Much appreciated.